# Remove substring from the string

Tags: ruby, string

I am just wondering if there is any method to remove string from another string?
Something like this:

```
class String
  def remove(s)
    self[s.length, self.length - s.length]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You can use the slice method:

```
a = "foobar"
a.slice! "foo"
=> "foo"
a
=> "bar"
```

there is a non '!' version as well. More info can be seen in the documentation about other versions as well:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-slice-21

Comment: Very elegant! You can also use `[]`s for the non-bang version.

Comment: This has a bad side effect of returning the deleted text (or text searched for). Unfortunate for chaining on the result of the deletion.

Comment: How do you return the sliced string and not affect the original? For example if I have "hello world", I want to slice "hello " and return just the "world" part, without modifying the original string object?

Comment: @Mike `"foobar".tap{|s| s.slice!("foo")}.upcase`

Comment: @jhabbott use `.delete()` for that

Comment: @bcackerman -- `delete` wouldn't work, since it deletes all the characters you pass in: `'hello world'.delete('hello') #=> ' wrd'`

Comment: @Mike Good call. I used `gsub`, which returns the original string, as @Piyush points out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5367181/293280

Comment: This modifies the string in place, and therefore will fail with `can't modify frozen String` if you try to do it on a frozen string. Using `.gsub` instead works.

Comment: Just a heads up that the URL you have is broken. You can find the slice documentation at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-slice.

Comment: slice! method will not modify the frozen strings, if you are using it inside the loop, in that  case use remove.

Comment: In case someone else is wondering as well `a = "Hello Heman!"; a.slice! "He" ; puts a` will print `llo Heman!`, it will not remove the second `He`.

Answer (score 191):

How about `str.gsub("subString", "")` 
Check out the [Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html)

Comment: `sub` would be more appropriate than `gsub`, since the OP only wants to remove the substring from the *beginning* of the string, not all through the string (look at his sample code). And using a regex, like this, would be better: `str.sub(/^subString/, '')` -- because it ensures that the substring will definitely be removed only from the beginning.

Comment: @AlexD Using a regex would be better, but it's dangerous if we can't be sure `subString` doesn't include any regex special characters.

Comment: @DavidMoles, in this case, `/^subString/` is a literal, so we can be very sure it doesn't include any metacharacters. If you are substituting some other string into a regex, you can do this: `/#{Regexp.escape(str)}/`.

Comment: In the answer, yes, but not in the OP's question. Thanks for the pointer to `Regexp.escape()`, though.

Answer (score 131):

If it is a the end of the string, you can also use [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
"hello".chomp("llo")     #=> "he"
```

Comment: if the expression was a.chomp("llo"), chomp! is more precise.

Comment: This is cleaner than slice!, as this has no side effects.

Comment: If it is from the beginning of the string, you can also use `chomp` in combination with `reverse`: `"hello".reverse.chomp("he".reverse).reverse #=> "llo"`

Answer (score 63):

#### Ruby 2.5+

If your substring is at the beginning of in the end of a string, then Ruby 2.5 has introduced the methods for this:

- [delete_prefix](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-delete_prefix) for removing a substring from the beginning of the string
- [delete_suffix](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-delete_suffix) for removing a substring from the end of the string

Answer (score 57):

If you only have one occurrence of the target string you can use:

```
str[target] = ''
```

or

```
str.sub(target, '')
```

If you have multiple occurrences of target use:

```
str.gsub(target, '')
```

For instance:

```
asdf = 'foo bar'
asdf['bar'] = ''
asdf #=> "foo "

asdf = 'foo bar'
asdf.sub('bar', '') #=> "foo "
asdf = asdf + asdf #=> "foo barfoo bar"
asdf.gsub('bar', '') #=> "foo foo "
```

If you need to do in-place substitutions use the `"!"` versions of `gsub!` and `sub!`.

Comment: ruby is fun! really enjoy seeing stuff like: `asdf['bar'] = ''`

Comment: I wouldn't call that "fun" - non-intuitive, perhaps.

Answer (score 42):

If you are using Rails there's also [`remove`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/remove).

E.g. `"Testmessage".remove("message")` yields `"Test"`.

Warning: this method removes *all* occurrences

Comment: This isn't a vanilla Ruby answer, but the accepted answer isn't quite what most people are looking for. Unfortunately the `slice` method doesn't return the portion of the string that's sliced, it returns the "knife"

Comment: @DylanPierce it's pretty easy to implement a function that does that using `slice!`

```def gimme_the_slice(my_string, my_slice)
  my_string.slice!(my_slice)
  my_string
```

Comment: Ah that's right, bang-ifying is how Ruby modifies the existing variable. Thanks @BennettTalpers

Answer (score 4):

If you are using rails or at less activesupport you got String#remove and String#remove! method

```
def remove!(*patterns)
  patterns.each do |pattern|
    gsub! pattern, ""
  end

  self
end
```

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-remove

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting right, this question seems to ask for something like a minus (-) operation between strings, i.e. the opposite of the built-in plus (+) operation (concatenation).

Unlike the previous answers, I'm trying to define such an operation that must obey the property:

***IF c = a + b THEN c - a = b AND c - b = a***

We need only three built-in Ruby methods to achieve this:

`'abracadabra'.partition('abra').values_at(0,2).join == 'cadabra'`.

I won't explain how it works because it can be easily understood running one method at a time.

Here is a proof of concept code:

```ruby
# minus_string.rb
class String
  def -(str)
    partition(str).values_at(0,2).join
  end
end

# Add the following code and issue 'ruby minus_string.rb' in the console to test
require 'minitest/autorun'

class MinusString_Test < MiniTest::Test

  A,B,C='abra','cadabra','abracadabra'

  def test_C_eq_A_plus_B
    assert C == A + B
  end

  def test_C_minus_A_eq_B
    assert C - A == B
  end

  def test_C_minus_B_eq_A
    assert C - B == A
  end

end
```

One last word of advice if you're using a recent Ruby version (>= 2.0): use [**Refinements**](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/) instead of monkey-patching String like in the previous example.

It is as easy as:

```
module MinusString
  refine String do
    def -(str)
      partition(str).values_at(0,2).join
    end
  end
end
```

and add `using MinusString` before the blocks where you need it.

Comment: +1 for the concepts of refinements. While monkey-patching String class is probably an overkill for this use case, sometimes we do have to monkey-patch things and concept of refinements really shines at it.

Answer (score -2):

here's what I'd do

```
2.2.1 :015 > class String; def remove!(start_index, end_index) (end_index - start_index + 1).times{ self.slice! start_index }; self end; end;
2.2.1 :016 >   "idliketodeleteHEREallthewaytoHEREplease".remove! 14, 32
 => "idliketodeleteplease" 
2.2.1 :017 > ":)".remove! 1,1
 => ":" 
2.2.1 :018 > "ohnoe!".remove! 2,4
 => "oh!"
```

Formatted on multiple lines:

```
class String
    def remove!(start_index, end_index)
        (end_index - start_index + 1).times{ self.slice! start_index }
        self
    end 
end
```