# Rails: Remove substring from the string if in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I know I can easily [remove a substring from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367164/remove-substring-from-the-string).

Now I need to remove every substring from a string, if the substring is in an array.

```
arr = ["1. foo", "2. bar"]
string = "Only delete the 1. foo and the 2. bar"

# some awesome function
string = string.replace_if_in?(arr, '')
# desired output => "Only delete the and the"
```

All of the functions to remove adjust a string, such as `sub`, `gsub`, `tr`, ... only take *one* word as an argument, not an array. But my array has over 20 elements, so I need a better way than using `sub` 20 times.

Sadly it's not only about removing words, rather about removing the whole substring as `1. foo`

How would I attempt this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like follows:

```
 arr = ["1. foo", "2. bar"]
 string = "Only delete the 1. foo and the 2. bar"

 arr.each {|x| string.slice!(x) }
 string # => "Only delete the  and the "
```

One extended thing, this also allows you to crop text with `regexp` service chars like `\`, or `.` (Uri's answer also allows):

```
 string = "Only delete the 1. foo and the 2. bar and \\...."
 arr = ["1. foo", "2. bar", "\..."]

 arr.each {|x| string.slice!(x) }
 string # => "Only delete the  and the  and ."
```

Comment: The dice decided to accept you ;) Thanks y'all for your help!

Comment: Note that if `string = "Only delete the 1. foo and the 2. bar and another 2. bar?"`, we get => `"Only delete the  and the  and another 2. bar?"` Is that's what's wanted? I don't know. Champ, you may wish to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `gsub` which accepts a regex, and combine it with [`Regexp.union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

```
string.gsub(Regexp.union(arr), '')
# => "Only delete the  and the "
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use #gsub with #join on the array elements

You can use #gsub by calling #join on the elements of the array, joining them with the regex alternation operator. For example:

```
arr = ["foo", "bar"]
string = "Only delete the foo and the bar"
string.gsub /#{arr.join ?|}/, ''
#=> "Only delete the  and the "
```

You can then deal with the extra spaces left behind in any way you see fit. This is a better method when you want to censor words. For example:

```
string.gsub /#{arr.join ?|}/, '<bleep>'
#=> "Only delete the <bleep> and the <bleep>"
```

On the other hand, split/reject/join might be a better method chain if you need to care about whitespace. There's always more than one way to do something, and your mileage may vary.

Comment: Using `join` is not optimal, since it does not escape the text in each element `1. foo` will match `11 foo` as well...

Comment: fyi: `1. foo` will match `11. foo` in all answers, so this answer is not inferior